# What is wrong with this simple C++ class program?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

**Please help I'm beginner level student in C++**
I'm failed to find a proper solution.I also added error image in this question.Please give me answer with proper solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class test
{
    int no;
    static int count;
    public:
        void getval (int);
        void dispcount (void);

};

void test:: getval(int x)
{
    no = x;
    cout << "Number = " << no << endl;;
    count++;
}

void test::dispcount(void)
{
    cout << "Counten = " << count;
}
    int test::count;

int main()
{
    test t1,t2,t3;

    t1.dispcount();
    t2.dispcount();
    t3.dispcount();

    t1.getval(100);
    t2.getval(200);
    t3.getval(300);

    t1.dispcount();
    t2.dispcount();
    t3.dispcount();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[here is error.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3POM.png)

Comment: In order to find a proper solution, you need to identify the problem. Have you done so?

Comment: Do not include hard-to-read images in questions, like this, in your question. You must include error messages as plain text. As a C++ beginner, the best skill you need to learn is how to communicate your issues in a way that everyone else can understand you.

Comment: Use `std::cout << ...`.

Comment: Your error message seems pretty clear, change `cout` to `std::cout` and `endl` to `std::endl` like it tells you.

Comment: You didnt put the image, anyhow you should post the complete error message as text not as image

Comment: @KamalMrock Please do as asked for and post the verbatim error text.

Comment: "Image added" after people tell you not to post image. Naughty.

Comment: Actually, this was my first question on this site.....and next time I will not add any image at the place of error ,only plain text, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Include directive

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
//..
```

Or include using declarations like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
//...
```

Or use qualified names as for example

```
void test:: getval(int x)
{
    no = x;
    std::cout << "Number = " << no << std::endl;
    ^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^^^
    count++;
}
```

Identifiers `cout` and `endl` are declared in namespace `std` and not in the global namespace.

Comment: Beginner C++ programmers should not really be exposed to [bad programming habits like "using namespace std;"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am sure that they start to learn C++ by using the using directive. And in any case any programmer should know all possibilities.

Comment: You are great.....

Comment: @KamalMrock u should propably intialize test::count ,because you're using it in t1.dispcount() without intialization and that would give a warning set it equal to 0

Comment: @MekacherAnis It is initialized by the compiler to 0 as an object with the static storage duration.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow didn't know that's even possible :P , so does all compilers do so ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis It is a requirement of the C++ Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank's for the new info bro